# Can't get select2 to work when using simple_form and cocoon

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, nested-attributes, jquery-select2

I've got an application that is using simple_form, cocoon, bootstrap-sass, and select2 all in the same form.  I've got everything working with select2 and styled correctly for the first object that gets displayed, which, I believe, is not setup by cocoon. However, any objects that I add with the link_to_add_fields option have neither the correct in-line styling or use select2.

The first form shows up like the following:

[image: This is the format for first object in form]

This is how the link_to_add_fields is adding the object:

[image]

I've tried using the callbacks to call select2 on the before/after insert and I couldn't get it to work.

Hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Here are my models:

```
class Week < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :pool
  has_many   :games, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :games

end
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :week

end
```

Controller code:

```
  def new
    @pool = Pool.find(params[:pool_id])
    if !@pool.nil?
      @week = @pool.weeks.new
      @game = @week.games.build
      @week.weekNumber = @pool.weeks.count + 1
    else
      flash[:error] = "Cannot create week. Pool with id:#{params[:pool_id]} does not exist!"
      redirect_to pools_path
    end
  end

  def create
    @pool = Pool.find(params[:pool_id])
    @week = @pool.weeks.new(week_params)
    @week.weekNumber = @pool.weeks.count + 1
    if @week.save
      # Handle a successful save
      flash[:success] = 
          "Week #{@week.weekNumber} for '#{@pool.name}' was created successfully!"
      # Set the state to Pend
      @week.setState(Week::STATES[:Pend])
      redirect_to @pool
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Here are the form views:

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Create Week #{@week.weekNumber}") %>
<%= raw "<h1>Create Week #{@week.weekNumber}</h1>" %>
<%= simple_form_for([@pool, @week], html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :games do |g| %>
    <%= render 'game_fields', f: g %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add New Game', f, :games %><br /><br />
  <%= f.button :submit, label: "Create week",
               class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

_game_fields.html.erb

```
<div class='nested-fields well'>
  <fieldset>
    <%= f.input :awayTeamIndex, label: false,
                    collection: NflTeam.all, value_method: :id,
                    label_method: :name,
                    placeholder: "Away Team",
                    include_blank: true, 
                    input_html: { id: "awayteam", class: 'span3' } %>
    <%= f.input :homeTeamIndex, label: false,
                    collection: NflTeam.all, value_method: :id,
                    label_method: :name,
                    placeholder: "Home Team",
                    include_blank: true,
                    input_html: { id: "hometeam", class: 'span3' } %>
    <%= f.input :_destroy, as: :hidden %>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f %>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript code I'm using (or at least trying to use in the case of the cocoon callbacks) :

```
/* Setup the select2 functions */
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('select#hometeam').select2({
    placeholder: "Home Team",
    allowClear: true
  });

  $('select#awayteam').select2({
    placeholder: "Away Team",
    allowClear: true
  });

  $('select#pick').select2();
});

/* setup cocoon nested forms insertion mode */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.add_fields").
    data("association-insertion-position", 'before').
    data("association-insertion-node", 'this');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#awayTeamIndex')
      .on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
        /* ... do something ... */
        $('select#awayteam').select2({
          placeholder: "Away Team",
          allowClear: true
        });
      });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to capture the callback on `#awayTeamIndex`, but as far as I can see in your code, that is an input-field. You should put the callback on a container-element that contains the inserted elements.

E.g. write

```
$('form').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
  /* apply select2 styling */ 
});
```

To make sure the callback is hit, you can always add an `alert` or `console.log`.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! I didn't quite understand your example,